# Python request not retriving same page information

Tags: python, batch-file, python-requests

Im trying to do some web scrape using python. My code is working well in pycharm, but when i try to run it from window CMD, the request is not returning the same page information as in pycharm.

CODE:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

resp = get('https://instagram.com/{}'.format('nfl'))
soup = bs(resp.text, 'html.parser')
```

ON pycharm ( first rows of the html page )

```
<html class="no-js not-logged-in client-root" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title>
**NFL (@nfl) • Instagram photos and videos**
</title>
```

ON WINDOWS CMD with the same code

```
<html class="no-js not-logged-in client-root" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title>
**Login • Instagram**
</title>
```

It seems like on windows cmd it ignores the page name "nfl", and it is requesting just https://www.instagram.com/

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you fix your `user-agent` to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0` for the script and the check? You can do this by creating a dict `headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'}`, and passing that in the request by `get(<url>,headers=headers)`. Do let me know if this changes some things for you.

Comment: @Mooncrater, not working with that modification. Still same response on windows cmd

Comment: Okay. One thing you can do is print the url of the page you're requesting. Use `print(resp.url)` for this. Note that even if the site does a redirect, the final URL is printed. So this should give some clarity.

Comment: @Mooncrater for some reason it is modifying my get with the add of "accounts/login" 
 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/nfl/

Comment: Well my first guess would be that pycharm and windows are using **different python versions**, so `requests` might behave differently in those cases. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense for the same script to give different outputs when the environment is the same.

Comment: @Mooncrater i guess the problem is that im doing the request on a virtual machine, and  in that environment it is not showing the page i want. Instead, is redirecting to the login page . In my regular machine the browser it's not redirecting me to login page, and for that reason it is working.